# SWT composite is visible only after opening the view twice in eclipse RCP

Tags: java, plugins, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have a view with composite and scrolledcomposite. But on click of the view first time, it is empty. If I close it and open again, the fields are visible. Please find the code snippet below.

```
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {

    parent.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,false));
    parent.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.CENTER, SWT.TOP, true, true));
    parent.setBackground(ApplicationColor.WHITEBACKGROUND);

    ScrolledComposite scrollComposite = new ScrolledComposite(parent, SWT.V_SCROLL|   
              SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.BORDER);
    main_composite = new Composite(scrollComposite, SWT.NONE);
    main_composite.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
    main_composite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.CENTER, SWT.TOP, true, true));
    main_composite.setBackground(ApplicationColor.WHITEBACKGROUND);
    main_composite.setSize(1700, 700);
    scrollComposite.setContent(main_composite);

    scrollComposite.setExpandHorizontal(true);
    scrollComposite.setExpandVertical(true);
    scrollComposite.setBackground(ApplicationColor.WHITEBACKGROUND);
    scrollComposite.setBackgroundMode(SWT.INHERIT_DEFAULT);
    GridData firstData = new GridData(SWT.CENTER, SWT.TOP, true, true);
    scrollComposite.setLayoutData(firstData);
    scrollComposite.addListener(SWT.Activate, new Listener() {
        public void handleEvent(Event e) {
            scrollComposite.setFocus();
        }
    });
    scrollComposite.addListener( SWT.Resize, event -> {
        int height = main_composite.getClientArea().height;
        int width = main_composite.getClientArea().width;
        scrollComposite.setMinSize( parent.computeSize( width, height ) );
    } );

    top_composite = new Composite(main_composite, SWT.NONE);
    top_composite.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, false));
    top_composite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.CENTER, SWT.TOP, true, true));
    top_composite.setBackground(ApplicationColor.WHITEBACKGROUND);
}
```

Comment: I can't really reproduce this and you haven't actually shown us any of the fields. Because your are calling `main_composite.setSize(1700, 700)` you might have to scroll the view to see your data.

Comment: Thank you for the hint greg. The fields are swt.table which is set inside main_composite. The problem was making main_composite.setSize(1700, 700). Instead I have edited the size of the parent. Now it works fine.